# how to resize image to the containing ImageView

Tags: ios, image, swift, uiimageview, swift2

I have an UIImageView sized 300x300.
When I pick and populate it with a bigger image than 300x300, how do I make it 
scale down to fit the UIImageView?

Do notice, this is only for display purposes, not actual resizing of the image. I try to achieve the same effect of the `height` and `width` attributes of an `image` tag in HTML.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109114/set-contentmode-of-uiimageview)

Comment: change content mode..or you are looking for something else

Answer (score 0):

Its just

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

or

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Also consider to use

```
yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

This works like `overflow: hidden` in CSS

Comment: What is the difference between the first two?

Comment: The first one fills your imageView completely with your images smallest side and "overflows" the larger side to show its content aspect ratio... The second one fills your imageView completely with your images largest side and keeps "empty" areas on the smallest side if the image is smaller than your imageView... also aspect ratio

Comment: Would u like me to add this to the answer?

Comment: Ahhh.. I am doing something wrong, tried all three options, seem to have no effect.