# How do I center and aspect fit an image in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, image

I have a project in Swift 3 that I am using a gradient on the view. I placed a image on the view, but it is under the gradient layer so I was going to draw the image programmatically instead of with the storyboard. I can't seem to figure out how to get the image to be centered and to aspect fit inside the bounds of the view.

What I have...

```
//Gradient Background
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.frame
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 147/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor, UIColor(red: 162/255, green: 134/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

//Image
let mainImage = UIImage(named:"WhiteLogoFront")
var mainImageView = UIImageView(image:mainImage)
self.view.addSubview(mainImageView)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set contentMode of UIImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109114/set-contentmode-of-uiimageview)

Comment: Please attached both image what is expected by u..and what you are getting currently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try it

```
let mainImage = UIImage(named:"WhiteLogoFront")
    var mainImageView = UIImageView(image:mainImage)
    mainImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: can you give the frame to main image view as mainImage.frame = CGRect(x: , y: , width: , height: )

Comment: set x, y height and width as you want

Answer (score 1):

```
 let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 147/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor, UIColor(red: 162/255, green: 134/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

    //Image
    let mainImage = UIImage(named:"WhiteLogoFront")
    var mainImageView = UIImageView(image:mainImage)
    mainImageView.center = self.view.cente
    mainImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(mainImageView)
```

Try this one