# Custom tableview cell image stretched

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

first post on this website so excuse any faults.

im having trouble with my image in custom cells in tableview, the image is set to width 345, height: 200 and 200 away from border and cellsize is 400 width. But when it launches everything is fine except image is displayed at about 1000 width instead of 200.

[image: Runtime screenshot]

the image content mode is set to scale to fill, clips to bounds. but have tried aspect fit, and same problem.

```
extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource {


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 10
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"searchCell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

[image: constraint image]

Comment: What's your code to populate your `UIImageView`? Try tweaking your content mode for your image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109114/set-contentmode-of-uiimageview

Comment: Check your `UIImageView` constraints

Comment: its just a test image i used set in the storyboard under attribute inspector

Comment: the constraints don't seem to have a problem, they are the right amount away from all angles, but somehow the cell width and the image size is increased for no reason.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your constraints to the question? Did you add a bottom constraint to the cell?

Comment: by changing content mode the image is the right size but the cellheight seems to still want to be overly long, force cellheight?

Comment: it seems that the image view has leading and trailing constraints, not width constraint

Comment: Yep, problem solved. Didn´t even know those existed, sorry for amateurish mistake!